# Quit popup and previous webpage are coming together when i press back button

Tags: android, webview, main-activity

when I press back button then Quit popup and previous page (in webview) are coming together. It should go previous page first, on the last page it should ask to quit.
Plzzzzzzzz help

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.ravi.demoapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Fragment contentFragment;
    String testDevice = "D0A04359EA1ECE9BA0CD4B6F457A9991";
    String testDevice2 = "63C3530DA03C191310DB9AB8F0672E5C";
    String testDevice3 = "801F2141A1DC3F743363AFDFDC42AF3A";
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private AdView mAdView;
    boolean displayAd = false;
    WebView mainWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mainWebView.loadUrl(this.getString(R.string.channel_url));

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(testDevice)
                .addTestDevice(testDevice2)
                .addTestDevice(testDevice3)
                .build();

        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayAd = true;
//              View servername = findViewById(R.id.txt_List);
//              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) servername.getLayoutParams();
//              layoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mAdView.getId());
//              layoutparams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
//              servername.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                if (!displayAd) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Proceed to the next level.
            }
        });

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId (defined in values/strings.xml).
        mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();
        loadInterstitial();
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private InterstitialAd newInterstitialAd() {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Proceed to the next level.
                finish();
                //goToNextLevel();
            }
        });
        return interstitialAd;
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadInterstitial() {
        // Disable the next level button and load the ad.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(testDevice)
                .addTestDevice(testDevice2)
                .addTestDevice(testDevice3)
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){switch(keyCode){case 
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mainWebView.goBack();
            }else{
            finish(); return true;}}
    }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble 
up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /*
     * We call super.onBackPressed(); when the stack entry count is > 0. if it
     * is instanceof EmpListFragment or if the stack entry count is == 0, then
     * we prompt the user whether to quit the app or not by displaying dialog.
     * In other words, from EmpListFragment on back press it quits the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onShowQuitDialog();
    }

    public void onShowQuitDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Quit?");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        showInterstitial();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }

}
```

### Actvity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_server_list_unit_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ad_view"
        android:id="@+id/mainWebView">
    </WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code here and provide a better description.

Comment: When the back button is pressed, to which activity (or fragment) you want to go?

Comment: It is webview, on back press , want to go previous webpage

Comment: @Sudarshan i updated the code plzzzz.suggest what should i replace by what

Comment: @cylon i posted the code here. plz look into it and suggest me where should i change.

Comment: What problems are you facing (like error logs)?

Comment: @Sudarshan there is no error but when I press back button it is showing quite option directly without going previous webpage page.

Comment: @Sudarshan sir ! is there any other method to contact you, Skype or WhatsApp etc..

Comment: @Sudarshan thankyou sir! I'll thankful for life --- Ravi Kumar Soni (Lucknow)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more Activities? Try this:

```
Button buttonBack;

buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
//in your layout set  android:id="@+id/buttonBack" (this is just an example)

buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {    
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Stack implementation:** If you want to go previous webpage by pressing back button you have to do two things.

1. Override `onBackPressed`
2. Saved your previous web page address on `Stack`.

Declare a `String` type `stack`

```
private Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
```

When new url is loading put the current url into stack. Like

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      stack.add(url);
     }
 }
```

Now, override `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        if (stack.size() > 1 && stack != null) {
            stack.pop();
            load(stack.peek());
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Here, `load()` is a methoad for loading webpage.

```
  private void load(String urlToLoad) {

    pd = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait Loading...");
    pd.show();

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    webView.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

}
```

**With WebView Native API:** (As you describe)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(mainWebView.canGoBack())
        mainWebView.goBack();
    else
        onShowQuitDialog();
}
```

No need to Override `onKeyDown`

Comment: no need to define / implement a Stack here. WebView has is own API for this: WebView.canGoBack() and WebView.goBack(). Look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack()    and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goBack()

Comment: I used stack as I'd implemented on my project.